# Failed to get this value in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

while Am trying to get current element value in angular controller it throwing error as

```
  Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at m.fn.extend.val       (jquery.min.js:4:8638)
    at h.promise.then.$scope.validatev     (product.js:471:43)
```

var productApp = angular.module('productApp', ['ngRoute','ngProgress']);

**Javascript**

```
 productApp.controller('AddOrderController', 
   function($scope,$http) {
       $scope.validatev = function (dis,v)
                         {
                          console.log(angular.element(dis).val()); //this line throwing error as above mentioned
                        }
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" ng-blur="validatev(this,'req:true');" class="form-control"/>
```

i can't get the value by ng-model / name property as those are dynamic element in my code , so i'm trying to get that element value by **this** keyword. please help me to get the **this** value in controller

Comment: angular is not defined in your console.log ... you're not passing in a reference to it.. Anyway why are you calling `angular` ?

Comment: @Pogrindis i tried to get using $(dis).val() but still same issue.

Comment: use : `ng-model` from your view to retain a reference ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-) object :

**Javascript**

```
 productApp.controller('AddOrderController', 
   function($scope) {
       $scope.validatev = function (event, v) {
           console.log(event.currentTarget, v);
       }
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" ng-blur="validatev($event,'req:true');" class="form-control"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using the ng-model on your input ?

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="modelRef.thingToValidate" ng-blur="validatev(modelRef);" class="form-control"/>
```

Then In your JS you have a reference to the input value..

```
$scope.validatev = function (modelRef)
                        {
                          console.log(modelRef.thingToValidate); 
                        };
```

*Note I havent tested this but it just demonstrates the ng-model useage..*

Example : [Angular Form Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: ng-model and name both are dynamic fields in my code. that's why am not able to access the value